# Dialog with minimize and help button

Tags: qt, dialog

i'm trying to create a dialog that has only a minimize and a '?' button in the title bar.
but whenever i try

```
ui->setupUi(this);
this->setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint );
```

i get a dialog that has both minimize and maximize buttons.
any hints? (no pun intended)

Comment: As you're new here, don't forget to inform youself about the accept and up-vote features.

Comment: So have you found another solution or did you find the answer yourself 5 minutes later and forgot about your question on a feedback-based Q&A site?

Answer (score 1):

What about `this->layout()->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetFixedSize)`. This makes the dialog unresizable and removes the min and max button and with your above code you then should get the min button back.

Answer (score 0):

If it's jQuery UI dialog, see my answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11561470/335514

and fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jasonday/ZSk6L/